# Windows C SetThreadDesktop() in an elevated state

Tags: c, windows

I've been trying to figure out why SetThreadDesktop() only works in a non-elevated state.
I can't find any information on this anywhere.

If I run the below program as a user it works completely fine, however if I attempt to run it as administrator I get the following error from SetThreadDesktop(): `Error: The requested resource is in use.`

Is it just simply not possible to use it as an administrator? I'm at a complete loss.

EDIT:
I have since discovered, that this error doesn't occur if you execute it from an elevated command prompt, however, if you execute it, say, from file explorer by right clicking Run as administrator the error does occur.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HDESK hDesk = CreateDesktop(TEXT("test"), NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
    printf("Desktop handle: %p\n", hDesk);
    
    if (SetThreadDesktop(hDesk) == 0) {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        if (error != 0) {
            LPSTR messageBuffer = NULL;
            size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, error, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);
            printf("Error: %s\n", messageBuffer);
            LocalFree(messageBuffer);
            while (1) {Sleep(10000);}
        }
    }
    while (1) Sleep(100000);
}
```

Comment: `while (1) Sleep(100000);` shows the program is still running. I can't replicate the behaviour though. I have to open another console to run another version of the program that is still running, and it runs whether or not I open the console as administrator.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats to keep it running so it doesn't exit before you can check if there was an error

Comment: It keeps running until I stop it (in a console). And then I can run it again, whether or not I have admin permission. None of them print the "Error..." etc.

Comment: Perhaps an earlier faulty version of the code has left a thread running. Try rebooting or looking in Task Manager to see if that is so.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you run it from an elevated command prompt is appears to work fine, however, running it from file explorer will cause that error.

Comment: Because it is being run from the same process? But I still can't replicate the problem, running from the file explorer, or the file explorer with admin permission.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats very weird. Are you using Windows 10 or 11?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I rejected Windows 10, and frankly, it's too much of an upheaval to decamp to later versions, when my system does what I want it to do.

Comment: ....I do however use the 2022 Microsoft 64-bit tools and documentation.